# Retrieve two values from the same row using a single select statement

Tags: java, sql

Why can't I retrieve two values from different fields but same row?

If I write this, it works perfectly.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM soal ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";    
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
String question = rs.getString("questions");
```

But after I add this

```
String hint = rs.getString("hint_questions");
```

It won't work.

NOTE: I need two Strings, `question`, and `hint` from the same row and class for different purpose. So I have to use single `select` query SQL so that value from `question` and `hint` is related (from the same row).

Comment: *it won't work.*, any error, any exception or just blank face ?

Comment: try retrieving using index.

Comment: If you need the two column values for the columns ``question`` and ``hint``, you can get them using ``rs.getString("question");`` and ``rs.getString("hint");``. Your code does something different though.

Comment: your code searches for `hint_questions` which does not exist

Comment: can u provide the tabel structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Either of the solution:

```
String var = rs.getString(1);
through index
```

Or

```
String var = rs.getString("column_name");
through column name
```